# Theorem about Polynomial Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am read Abstrac Álgebra, Gallian and I am thinking how to prove this Theorem
The first implications is ready but the second implication I dont know... 
Can you give me a Idea. 
Let F be a field, I a nonzero ideal in F[x], and g(x) an element of F[x]. Then, I=⟨g(x)⟩ if and only if g(x) is a nonzero polynomial of minimum degree in I.

Comment: What is the second implication for you?

Comment: if g(x) is a nonzero polynomial of minimum degree in I Then, I=⟨g(x)⟩

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If what you call the second implication is having a minimal degree ensures we have generator for $I$, for any polynomial $f(x)$, perform a euclidean division by $g(x)$. What can you say of the remainder $r(x)$?